# is there any library in java for unit conversion?

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I want to use unit conversions like kg to grams, lit to ml, etc.. is there any java library  and my-sql tables, available for this ?

I was asked to use JScience so now I have to populate all the units in  JScience into a JCombo box or a list box.. Tel me hod do i do that please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [JScience](http://jscience.org/)...

Here's an example to convert kilogram to gram:-

```
    double gram = Measure.valueOf(5, SI.KILOGRAM).doubleValue(SI.GRAM);
    System.out.println(gram);
```

Here are all the available units:-

```
    for (Unit<?> unit : SI.units()) {
        System.out.println(unit);
    }
```

The print outs:

```
m/s?
F
lm
A
C
N
H
J
lx
K
m/s
Wb
m?
Gy
T
W
kg
V
Ω
S
kat
Pa
sr
m
m?
mol
bit
°C
Hz
s
Bq
Sv
rad
cd
```

By the way, I'm using the [JRE 1.4 compatible binary from JScience](http://jscience.org/jscience-vm14.jar), and I also need JSR 275 (I pulled that from Maven):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.measure</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr-275</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here're my import statements, if anyone cares:-

```
import javax.measure.units.SI;
import javax.measure.units.Unit;
import org.jscience.physics.measures.Measure;
```

Comment: can i use this for all kind of conversions. like weight, vloume, length etc ??

Comment: how do i populate all the units in Jscience into a JListbox ?

Comment: eg is fine.. i just want to list all the units for the users so is there any way to get it from this library and lsiting it ?

Comment: @limc - your example doesn't match the javadoc.  Shurely some mistook?

Comment: @stephen, there are 2 different jars from jscience. I can't get the 5.0 snapshot to work, somehow it is missing APIs in the jar. So, right now, I'm using the JDK 1.4 jar (from the same website)... and that works.

Comment: @stephen: I removed the javadoc link from my post, but I added the jars and my import statements above, in case you are interested to know which classes I used.

Comment: @deepak: I did a printout of all the supported units from that API... see my post above.

Comment: This is the right answer.  I've used this on some projects and it works great.  You can also define your own units if you want, which is useful for some cases.